# Keep only geometry with certain amount of height difference

Tags: selection-tools

I'm trying to post process a navigation mesh that I will send into a another product for baking audio environment data for our game.  If I send in the entire navmesh for the terrain it will take weeks to process. So I want to send a navmesh that only contains non flat geo. Hills, etc. And also a buffer zone around these zones. Can I use Blende to automate this process?

I basically want it to select all hills with a little padding, and So I can invert it and delete that geo. Or vice versa.

Comment: Maybe use *Select Similar > By Normal*?

Comment: You can select a flat face, Shift+G > Normal to select all faces with similar direction, Ctrl+Numpad- to contract the selection for the buffer and delete them. You can do similar things in Geometry Nodes dynamically: https://i.imgur.com/u4mdRI7.png But I'm gonna guess you wouldn't want the result to be so patchy, right? You kinda want it to recognize that sth is a hill even if small parts of it are flat and preserve it as a whole? That'd be much harder.

Comment: @Kuboå Yeah I would want it to use some sort of local maxima (local peak) threshhold. Ideal I would just change a threshhold and see the selection of quads change That would be a easy workflow

Comment: A Geometry Nodes setup (or a Python script) like I've shown would be dynamic, but the math of adding locality considerations is above my paygrade unfortunately. You could have a go at that if you're alright with the math.

Comment: @Kuboå Im a programmer. But then I might do it directly in Unity game engine instead which Im familiar with.  It would be something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218037/how-to-find-local-maxima-in-image

Comment: you can smooth and expand / contract selections in vertex paint mode... and maybe those flat zones are on a certain height range? that could be part of the selection mecanic...